# How to create new php mail instance for each row in array

Tags: php, email

Here's the php:

```
mysqli_connect("path","my_db","password")or die(); 
mysqli_select_db("my_db")or die();
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = '$var' OR type = '$othervar'";
$result=mysqli_query($query);
$num=mysqli_numrows($result);
mysqli_close();
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$email=mysqli_result($result,$i,"email");
$i++;

if (!empty($email)) {
mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
```

I left out the script assigning value to $subject, etc. because I am able to successfully send an email when there is only 1 email address returned from the query.

However, when the query returns multiple email addresses, I'm unable to send anything.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $email=mysql_result($result,$i,"email");
try using mysqli_result

Comment: Nice catch!  Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Put some echo's to see if everything is as expected. Echo $i in your while loop, echo $email, and $num to see you are actually getting some data from the database.

Comment: so when I echo $email, it displays like this: "johndoe@gmail.comJaneDoe@gmail.comBillBob@yahoo.com"  All crunched together. Do you think that is an issue?   Other echoes were fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "GROUP BY..." to the end of my query ended up working for me.  Because I'm a total amateur, I have no idea why :)

Final code:

```
mysqli_connect("path","my_db","password")or die(); 
mysqli_select_db("my_db")or die();
$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = '$var' OR type = '$othervar' GROUP BY email";
$result=mysqli_query($query);
$num=mysqli_numrows($result);
mysqli_close();
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$email=mysqli_result($result,$i,"email");
$i++;

if (!empty($email)) {
mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
```